# Rails type of relation between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models: **User**, **Order** and **Car** and I have question because I don't know what relationships between these models will be the best. Only requirement is that only one car per user in order.

Comment: This is more of a logic question, but one approach can be many orders to one user and one car to one order. This assumes that every order has one car in it... I suggest you reformulate your question to include details and we can help you on the coding.

Comment: Hmm I have only one requirement when I create a new order. When I finalize order no more cars can be added.

Comment: Is it me, or is your question not really clear? You have 3 models. You can't even describe the relationship between them. So how are we supposed to give you an answer? Maybe you could provide more than two sentences that described your problem.

Comment: User can create order with only one car. What more is need? Sorry for my english maybe I can't describe this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user can have many orders, and therefore, many cars through those orders.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :cars, through: :orders
end
```

An order belongs to a user and a car.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :car
end
```

A car has one order.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need one on one relationship between order and car and then back to order and customer one relationship. Something below should do the trick.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order
  has_one :customer, through: :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :customer 
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order
  has_one :car , through: :order
end
```

But i will suggest the has_many relationship by the looks of the model name, but you know better your problem than me.